# Rename Layers based on geometry type (line, area, point)

Tags: qgis, layers, geometry, batch

I have numerous in memory layers that I need to export as shapefiles.

The problem is, many of them have the same names; for example I have  "railway_station" 3 times... as a point, line, and polygon.  If I batch export these as is, I get dropped layers.

I would like to rename these layers by appending some text to identify the geometry type... so that when I export I get all layers correctly to shapefiles.

Using railway_station as example, they would become:

- railway_station_a  (for polygon areas)
- railway_station_l  (for lines)
- railway_station_p  (for points)

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in QGIS Python console. First, list all the layers, then iterating into all layers, get each layer's geometry type and set new name. Here is the code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer

# list all layers and iterating into all of them
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():

    layer_name = layer.name()  # get layer name

    # get layer type and set new name
    if layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.Point:
        layer.setLayerName(layer_name + '_Point')
    elif layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineString:
        layer.setLayerName(layer_name + '_Line')
    elif layer.geometryType() == QgsWkbTypes.Polygon:
        layer.setLayerName(layer_name + '_Polygon')
```

Comment: what will happen if there be a multi-part geometry?

Comment: This is based on the scenario in the question, for other more complex situations, you can  look into the feature types.